# Targetting a column with a variable (R)

Tags: r, for-loop, command, repeat

I have a bad english, so sorry about that ;)

I am currently programming a little thing on r.

I have a lot of column in a data frame  (named data.frame) on R.

The name of the column is 1A, 1B, 2A, 2B, 3A, 3B,.......

I would like to run a  t test on each column (1A vs 1B), ...

my command is

```
t.test(data.frame$`1A`,data.frame$`1B`, paired=T,alternative="two.sided")
```

i thought of using the command for(i in 1:100), and use the variable i into the name of the column, but i dont know how to put a variable into the name of the column (i tried data.frame$i'A' and other thing, it didnt work...)

If you have any idea, i'll take it ;)

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
  for (i in 1:X){
  t<-t.test(data[,paste(i,"A",sep="")],data[,paste(i,"B",sep="")],    
  paired=T,alternative="two.sided")
  print(t)
  }
```

(I changed the name of the data.frame in data so that no one gets confused)

Comment: You should change `X` with `seq_along(data)`.

Comment: I thought about it, but because the column number is not the same as the loop variable I choose the easy way;) (i from 1:100 -> dataframe with 200 columns)

'length(colnames(t))/2' would be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#Create sample dataset

`1A`<-sample(1:1000, 1000)
`1B`<-sample(1:1000, 1000)
`2A`<-sample(1:1000, 1000)
`2B`<-sample(1:1000, 1000)

table1<-data.frame(`1A`,`1B`,`2A`,`2B`)


#Generate nested do loop for all compinations of pairs
for (i in 1:ncol(table1)) {
  for (j in 1:ncol(table1))  {

    txt=paste0("t.test(table1$",names(table1[i]),",table1$",names(table1[j]),",paired=T,alternative='two.sided')")

    t<-eval(parse(text = txt))
    print(t)

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for the help!

Ive used mainly the Martin method : here what worked for me :

```
for(i in 1:(ncol(data.frame)/2)){
a<-data.frame[,paste(i,"A",sep="")]
#the problem  was the creation each time of a new data.frame (witch was a, with one colomn, the good one, bur the colomn name didnt change.... i rename it
names(a)[1]<-"A"
b<-data.frame[,paste(i,"B",sep="")]
names(b)[1]<-"B"
t.test(a$'A',b$`B`, paired=T,alternative="two.sided")
}
```

Thx a lot!!